# como mostrar el contenido del atributo title de la etiqueta <a> que esta en el index1.html, en un input que esta en el index2.html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, fetch

al dar click quiero mostrar el contenido del atributo "title" de la etiqueta `<a>` que esta en la hoja index1.html, en un `input` que esta en la hoja index2.html?
tengo este código pero no muestra nada en el input

```
<!-- html index1.html -->

<a href="/pruab.html" class="links" title="Título del enlace 1">Enlace 1</a> 
<a href="/pruab.html" class="links" title="Título del enlace 2">Enlace 2</a>
<a href="/pruab.html" class="links" title="Título del enlace 3">Enlace 3</a>
```

```
<!-- html index2.html -->

<input type="text" id="inputlist">
```

```
<!-- JavaScript -->

fetch("index1.html")
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(html => {
    // Crea un elemento temporal para parsear el HTML
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
    
    // Obtiene todos los elementos <a> con la clase link
    const links = doc.querySelectorAll(".links");
    
    // Agrega un manejador de eventos click a cada enlace
    links.forEach(link => {
      link.addEventListener("click", event => {
        // Obtiene el valor del atributo title del enlace que se hizo click
        const title = event.target.getAttribute("title");
        
        // Asigna el valor del atributo title al elemento input
        document.getElementById("inputlist").value = title;
      });
    });
  });
```